# Silex: Redirect with Flash Data

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301, silex

I need to redirect one page to another with a message in Silex. Hopefully there's a Laravelesque way of doing it, but I highly doubt it:

```
$app->redirect('/here', 301)->with('message', 'text');
```

I'd then want to display the message in my template:

```
{{ message }}
```

If not, is there another way?

#### Update

I see there's a `getFlashBag` method in Symfony - is that what I'm supposed to use? Specifically, I am using the Bolt Content Management system.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, FlashBag is the right way.
Set a flash message in your controller (you can add multiple messages):

```
$app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'text');
$app->redirect('/here', 301)
```

And print it in the template:

```
{% for message in app.session.getFlashBag.get('message') %}
    {{ message }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: To expand on @a4c8b answer, please note that this will create a session cookie for every request. To fix it, please add `peekAll`, see [Nyholm's gist](https://gist.github.com/Nyholm/4c2a960531d5d81c062b)

Answer (score 5):

I created this simple `FlashBagTrait` that may be of use:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;

trait FlashBagTrait
{
    /**
     * @return FlashBagInterface
     */
    public function getFlashBag() {
        return $this['session']->getFlashBag();
    }
}
```

Just add it to your `Application` class and it will make things ever-so-slightly easier!

```
$app->getFlashBag()->add('message',array('type'=>"danger",'content'=>"You shouldn't be here"));

{% if app.flashbag.peek('message') %}
<div class="row">
    {% for flash in app.flashbag.get('message') %}
        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-{{ flash.type }}">
            <p>{{ flash.content }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Its main advantage is that type-hinting will work in PhpStorm.

You can also add it as a service provider,

```
$app['flashbag'] = $app->share(function (Application $app) {
    return $app['session']->getFlashBag();
});
```

Which makes it more convenient to use from PHP (but you lose the type-hinting):

```
$app['flashbag']->add('message',array('type'=>"danger",'content'=>"You shouldn't be here"));
```